# Should I dispose of manually a Dictionary data structure after I am done using it?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, coding-style, dispose

Is it worth the effort to try and actively dispose of the `Dictionary` in this code, or just leave it to managed garbage collection?

```
private void LogReprocessTsk(List<ReprocessTsk> reprocessTsks)
{
    foreach (ReprocessTsk reprocessTsk in reprocessTsks)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> logMessage = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "Message", "insert into REPROCESS_TSK - parentId changed" },
            { "TSKLOC", reprocessTsk.TSKLOC },
            { "CRS", reprocessTsk.CRS.ToString() },
            { "PROCESSED", reprocessTsk.PROCESSED.ToString() },
            { "OldParentId", reprocessTsk.OldParentId },
            { "NewParentId", reprocessTsk.NewParentId }
        };

        _logger.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logMessage));
    }
}
```

Comment: Premature Optimization isn't a good idea. You have a Dictionary of only strings. Why does it matter _when_ garbage collection happens? Have you measured a meaningful bottleneck in your application due to this?

Comment: This might also be an X/Y problem, seeing that you're creating a dictionary for the soul purpose of JSON serializing it. Can your logger method not take complex objects?

Comment: Premature Optimization isn't a good idea - got it. 

I'll leave it to garbage collection. I was just wondering because inside a tight loop, there could be any number of them. However, this will never result in a bottle neck (I think) because the cost of series of strings is insignificant compared to memory resources today.

Comment: You could create a single Dictionary before the loop and call `logMessage.Clear();` instead of re-creating a dictionary every time. Other solution: just keep the same dict without clearing it and and re-assign the entries with `logMessage["key"] = "value";`. This automatically replaces any existing entries and adds new ones.

Comment: should dispose only unmanaged resources like connection, or file etc. here GC should do its work. You should optimize as per suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The garbage collector does its job very well and there is no reason to force a premature garbage collection. The dictionary gets out of the scope of the loop anyway at each iteration and becomes automatically a candidate for garbage collection.

You can minimize the number of object creations if you declare only one dictionary before the loop and clear it after use.

```cs
var logMessage = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (ReprocessTsk reprocessTsk in reprocessTsks) {
    logMessage.Add("Message", "insert into REPROCESS_TSK - parentId changed");
    logMessage.Add("TSKLOC", reprocessTsk.TSKLOC);
    logMessage.Add("CRS", reprocessTsk.CRS.ToString());
    logMessage.Add("PROCESSED", reprocessTsk.PROCESSED.ToString());
    logMessage.Add("OldParentId", reprocessTsk.OldParentId);
    logMessage.Add("NewParentId", reprocessTsk.NewParentId);

    _logger.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logMessage));
    logMessage.Clear();
}
```

Since you are using the same keys at each foreach iteration, yet another possibility is to re-assign the new values to the same dictionary keys.

```cs
var logMessage = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (ReprocessTsk reprocessTsk in reprocessTsks) {
    logMessage["Message"] = "insert into REPROCESS_TSK - parentId changed";
    logMessage["TSKLOC"] = reprocessTsk.TSKLOC;
    logMessage["CRS"] = reprocessTsk.CRS.ToString();
    logMessage["PROCESSED"] = reprocessTsk.PROCESSED.ToString();
    logMessage["OldParentId"] = reprocessTsk.OldParentId;
    logMessage["NewParentId"] = reprocessTsk.NewParentId;

    _logger.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logMessage));
}
```

Note that the dictionary indexer creates non existing entries and replaces existing ones. See: the [remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item?view=net-7.0#remarks) for the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Item[TKey]` Property.